# Create node with angularjs

Tags: nodes

I have created web service of content and views that will export content in JSON format. Now I'm getting node data with simply call web service path with $http.get(...) It will successfully loads the all node. But Im not able to  create(actually don't know how to create) with Drupal web service and angularJs.

Answer (score 1):

You Should mention for which drupal version you needs solution. Anyways, in drupal you need to mention for what you actions you are creating REST service. Like for reading a post, or creating a post or maybe to update or delete a post or user or any other entity. There are several tutorials out there. If you would google, then you will easily find one. However, by following below link you can easily create REST service for creating a node also.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Hope this helps, if you need solution for Drupal 7 then google it, you will get numerous. If you are a visual learner then there are also good quality video tutorials on youtube as well.